# calculating probability of binomial distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

"100 questions, with 4 possible answers for each question. If you randomly select the answer for each question, what is the probability of passing the exam (obtaining 40% or more)"

x = ?
n = 100
p = 0.25
Calculating 40% or less is as simple as just inputting 40 for the value of x but how do I swap that around to 40% or more? I've tried -40, 60, -60 but clearly that's wrong.

**CODE**

```
import scipy.stats as stats

cum_binomalpha = stats.binom.pmf(40, n=100, p=0.25)
print(round(cum_binomalpha, 6))
```

**EDIT - LOVELY DOVELY SOLUTION**

```
import scipy.stats as stats

cumm_binomalpha = stats.binom.cdf(39, n=100, p=0.25)
print (round(1-cumm_binomalpha, 6))
```

Comment: `P(X > k) = 1 - P(X <= k)` Also you need to be using the *cdf* to calculate a cumulative probability, not the *pmf*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) to get an exact answer:

```py
from sympy import S
from sympy.stats import Binomial, P

b = Binomial('b', 100, S(1) / 4)
print(P(b >= 40).evalf(), P(b >= 40))
```

Result:

```
0.000686592207962991
68956946241719424989885392307281546441260036992065207027/100433627766186892221372630771322662657637687111424552206336
```

With scipy, you could try the following:

```py
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

print(stats.binom.pmf(np.arange(40, 101), n=100, p=0.25).sum())
print(1 - stats.binom.cdf(39, n=100, p=0.25))
```